# Asp.Net-Core with Razor Pages web app send values on Post method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Is it possible in Asp.Net-Core Webb Application with Razor Pages to send some values via the url and post method? I know that in MVC you would use the HttpPost method, but that is not possible in .Net Core.

For example, in my js file I have this function that receives a parameter a:

```
function redirect(a)
{
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: './MyPage', //I also tried @Url.Page("SetValue")'
      dataType: 'int',
      data: { a },
   });
}
```

I want to be able to send that value to my Razor Page, something like this:

```
public void OnPostSetValue(int a)
{         
    Debug.WriteLine(a); //here I will use the value       
}
```

But I am getting this error: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 () [https://localhost:44350/MyPage]"

I know that probably this is not the way to do it, but I only found examples for MVC. Is there any way I can do this here in Asp.Net Core?

Comment: You can pass the value a in query string. I mean with url

Comment: Do you mean something like: `url: './MyPage?i`

Comment: Yes . You got it right

Comment: But I still get the same error with status 500

Comment: Have you used FromUrl ?

Comment: No, where should I use it? In my razor page? Do you have a syntax example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I am getting this error: "Failed to load resource: the server
> responded with a status of 500 () [https://localhost:44350/MyPage]"

**You can do it in the Asp.Net Core with Razor Pages.**

First of all, there is no specific `post method name` specified in your `url` in ajax.

Secondly, there is a special requirement when using ajax to pass parameters in the Razor Pages, **we must provide the anti-forgery token ourselves**, which means we need to add **`@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`** in your page view, then add **`headers`** in ajax to pass the anti-forgery token.

For more details, please refer to [this](https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/asp-net-core-razor-pages-how-to-implement-ajax-requests/#how-to-handle-post-requests-with-the-xsrf-csrf-security-feature).

Here is the complete example:

```
@page
@model WebApplication_razorpage_new.Pages.MyPageModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "MyPage";
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
 
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="redirect(1)" />
 

@section Scripts{
    <script>
        function redirect(a) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Page("MyPage", "SetValue")',
                dataType: 'int',
                data: {a},
                headers: {
                    RequestVerificationToken: $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
}
```